# Xamarin.Forms display soft keyboard when Entry gets focus

Tags: keyboard, xamarin.forms

I have a cross platform Xamarin.Forms app and when I'd like to set focus on Entry and display soft keyboard when a page is loaded.  This works for iOS, but not for Android.  I just use the code below:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {

        pinCode.Focus();

        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some Hacks for this:

1.- Use Task.Delay(500); before the `Focus()` call.

2.- Use `pinCode.Focus();` on the constructor of the page.

The normal thing to do is to use the Dependency Service to force the soft keyboard to be showed.

This normally implies that you may have Thread blocking issues on your app.

Comment: Didn't focus at all if I put in constructor instead of OnAppearing.  Thanks

Comment: So for me, the way I go it to work was putting these two lines in the OnAppearing event BEFORE the call to base.OnAppearing() and putting them in this order:   await Task.Delay(500); myControl.Focus();

Answer (score 1):

Add following line in the constructor of your page

**Appearing += (object sender, EventArgs e) => pinCode.Focus();**

this worked for me!

Comment: This is the same what the mentioned. Btw, it also works for me (although only tested on emulator), however putting into the constructor does not work.